# How to add custom header to HTTP outbound-gateway to a secured REST service

Tags: spring-integration

my spring integration project is configured as follow:

1- JMS message-driven-channel-adapter to consume MQ XML messages.

2- HTTP outbound-gateway to send those XML messages to a secured REST service.

3- REST service requires an authentication token set in the HTTP request header.

To accomplish #3 I added to my configuration a header-enricher component in front of the outbound-gateway.

```
... --> DirectChannel --> Header-enricher --> DirectChannel --> HTTP outbound-gateway --> ...
```

The issue I am having is making the REST service request call with the token included in the header. Thus I am getting 401 error.

```xml
    <int-http:outbound-gateway 
            url="${outbound.rest.url}" 
            request-channel="httpOutboundRequestChannel" 
            reply-channel="httpOutboundReplyChannel" 
            http-method="POST" 
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"> 
    </int-http:outbound-gateway> 


    <int:header-enricher input-channel="httpHeaderEnricherChannel" output-channel="httpOutboundRequestChannel">
         <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/xml"/>
         <int:header name="X-My-Token" value="mytokenvaluehere"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
```

The log shows the "X-My-Token" header is being added to the message but not to the request of the outbound-gateway.

How to get custom header added to the outbound-gateway component?

Any suggestion is much appreciated!.

Logs:

```
20656 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG  org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel  
    preSend on channel 'httpOutboundRequestChannel', message:  GenericMessage [payload=my XML goes here, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMSXUserID=someid    , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1441991857194, JMSXAppID=WebSphere MQ Client for Java, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20150911, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, X-Auth-Token=mytokenvaluehere, JMS_IBM_PutTime=17173719, id=ffd41297-8320-912a-1bac-2dca14bb658a, jms_messageId=ID:414d512054315055434b2020202020205afce255021cf422, Content-Type=application/xml, timestamp=1441991857282}]
20656 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandlerorg.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0 received message: 
    GenericMessage [payload=my XML goes here, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMSXUserID=someid    , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1441991857194, JMSXAppID=WebSphere MQ Client for Java, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20150911, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, X-My-Token=mytokenvaluehere, MS_IBM_PutTime=17173719, id=ffd41297-8320-912a-1bac-2dca14bb658a, jms_messageId=ID:414d512054315055434b2020202020205afce255021cf422, Content-Type=application/xml, timestamp=1441991857282}]

20806 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  
        Created POST request for "https://my.rest.uri.here"
20809 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  
    Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
20810 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  Writing [my XML goes here] as "application/xml" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@1269bf3]

21413 [task-scheduler-8] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer  Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
21524 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  
    POST request for "https://my.rest.uri.here" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapped-request-headers` - see the [documentation section 'HTTP Header Mappings'](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping).

```
mapped-request-headers="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, X-My-Token"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gary for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Gary's answer, only standard HTTP headers will be mapped at the time the request is created. For adding any custom header, you can either use 'mapped-request-headers' if the header starts with 'X-' or specify your own DefaultHttpHeaderMapper as follows:

```
    <bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, My-Token" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>
```

HeaderPrefix needs to be defined for your custom headers to be picked up (default is 'X-' so other headers won't be mapped) as well as standard headers (HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS). The outbound-gateway can use your headerMapper like this:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway 
    url="${outbound.rest.url}" 
    request-channel="httpOutboundRequestChannel" 
    reply-channel="httpOutboundReplyChannel" 
    http-method="POST"
    header-mapper="headerMapper"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
```